# Symfony 4 forms CollectionType: make FileType element required for new rows only

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

I have an array of images that I want to be able to add to/update/delete from in a Symfony 4 form.

To create a form for these images, I'm using a custom form with a FileType in it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder
        ->add('image', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class' => null
        ))
    ;

}
```

I am then using a CollectionType filled with instances of the form described above to render a form for each of the images in the array, with 'allow_add' and 'allow_delete' so I can add/remove rows via JavaScript.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $builder->add('imagesets', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => ImageType::class,
        'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true
    ));
}
```

This works fine for adding new images, but when updating existing images, the FileType element shouldn't be required, it should only be required for the new rows.

**Question:** How can I make the FileType NOT required for existing images, yet required for all the new rows?

(Note, I will be passing plain arrays to these form objects, not Doctrine entities.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an [EventListener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) to your ImageType form and modify the *required* attribute if the object is not new (or not null). Have in mind that adding the second element with the same name as the previous to the form, replaces it.

```
$builder
    ->add('image', FileType::class, array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'required' => true,
    ))
    ;

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    // get the form object
    $form = $event->getForm();
    // get the entity/object data
    $image = $event->getData();
    // if it is new, it will be null
    if(null !== $image) {
        // modify the input
        $form->add('image', FileType::class, array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'required' => false,
        ))
         ;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer! The `true` and `false` need to be switched though. Thank you! :D

Comment: After writing the answer I reread your question to make sure the answer is correct and switched true and false, but didn't update the if clause, I'm sorry :-) it should be: null !== $image. Is that better?

Comment: No problem, and null !== $image actually makes more sense here than switching true/false, so I will use that. Thanks! :)